# iOS Custom UIView in Custom UITableViewCell Initialization and default properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I have a subclassed UIView control (MyCustomProgressView) that I am writing to use in multiple apps that will each be branded and am wondering how to make the control more user friendly for my team.  The control is a customized progress view that will usually be used within a custom UITableViewCell.

MyCustomProgressView has several properties that can be set to tailer it's appearance and behavior for each use.  I have given it an initializer that sets these to default values, but want the control to respect overriding of these defaults when used.

For example, in MyCusomProgressView.m:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [self setup];
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setup {
    //initialization
    [self setDelegate:nil];
    [self setCurrentProgress:0.0f];
    [self setLastProgress:0.0f];
    [self setAnimated:YES];
    [self setProgressColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self setProgressWidth:7.0f];
    [self setTrackWidth:5.0f];
    [self setDuration:0.2f];
    [self setProgressLabelColor:[UIColor: darkGrayColor];
}
```

Great.  Now, when I use the view from MyCustomTableViewCell, I want to do this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MyCusomProgressView *myProgView;
...

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code
    [self.myProgView setDuration:0.25f];
    [self.myProgView setProgressColor:[UIColor blueColor];
    [self.myProgView setProgressLabelColor:[UIColor yellowColor];
    [self.myProgView setTrackWidth:2.0];
    [self.myProgView setProgressWidth:3.0];
}
```

The problem is that when MyCustomTableViewCell loads MyCusomProgressView, the default initializer runs and overwrites the custom settings.  I know I can just modify MyCusomProgressView.m for each use, but I would prefer to keep that static if possible.

In case it matters, there are non xibs involved as I have done it all in storyboards and I am not doing anything odd in cellForRowAtIndexPath other than changing the signature for the the custom cell class:

```
- (MyCustomTableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyCustomTableViewCell *cell = (MyCustomTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];   
    // Configure the cell...
    [cell.myProgView setDelegate:self];
    return cell;
}
```

Any ideas?  I am sure it's something stupid simple...

Comment: Just to get what you try to do, you are setting up your customized TableViewCells with an "default" configuration in their init constructor, but you want to override this configuration values (if needed) in cellForRowAtIndexPath... Is that correct? I just need your info to give you the right answer :-)

Comment: Not exactly.  I am setting default values for my subclassed UIView control which is placed inside of a custom tableviewcell.  I am currently trying to override the defaults in the tableviewcell, but the defaults from the custom UIView are loading after they are set but he cell.  I was hoping to avoid setting the custom UIView properties from cellForRowAtIndexPath if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a question of the order in which your setup methods are called. Set breakpoints in `MyCusomProgressView` to see when `awakeFromNib` and `initWithFrame` are called. Also set breakpoint in `MyCustomTableViewCell` to see when its `awakeFromNib` is called.

If `initWithFrame` is getting called, try removing `awakeFromNib` entirely in your `MyCusomProgressView`.

Or try adding this line in your `MyCustomTableViewCell` `awakeFromNib` as the first line of code:

```
    [self.myProgView view];
```

This will force the progress view to load, calling its `awakeFromNib`. The downside is you don't want users of your progress view to have to do this because it's not obvious.

Comment: Thanks Mike. It seems that when the table loads, it first calls MyCustomTableViewCell's awakeFromNib, then calls MyCustomProgressView's awakeFromNib.  So even though I am setting the properties in the custom cell's implementation, they are over written by the custom control's own init.  When I add [self.myProgView view]; I get "No visible interface for 'MyCustomProgressView' declares the selector 'view'.

Comment: Removing awakeFromNib seems to have done it.  Thanks!